# how to solve "An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId)" AWS Chalice deployment error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm new to application development and decided to use AWS services for this project. however, I am having difficulty deploying chalice. every time I run "chalice deploy", I get an error.

here are the steps I followed along with commands for Windows:

1. upgraded my powershell
2. **"virtualenv enve"** : then **".\venv\Scripts\activate"**    #  install and run virtual environment
3. **"pip install aws cli**" : # install aws command line interface
4. **"aws configure"** :    # configure my AWS_KEY and AWS_SCERET
5. **"pip install chalice"**  :  # install chalice
6. **"chalice new-project"**: # created a new project
7. **"chalice deploy"**  # deploy

I get

> **An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetRole
> operation:  The security token included in the request is invalid.**

I'm able to use localhost and run my application but not able to deploy to the server. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. someone, please help!

additional info:
my operating system is windows 10. I upgraded my PowerShell to 7

Comment: I somehow figured it out!. The error occurred because the command "chalice deploy" was used in the wrong directory. Make sure you are in the directory where your chalice file is before initializing it to deploy. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I somehow figured it out!. The error occurred because the command "

> chalice deploy

" was used in the wrong directory. Make sure you are in the directory where your chalice file is before initializing it to deploy.